# Deploy Angular App in Heroku Error - mkdir '/dist' Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/dist'

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku

Based on [this](https://itnext.io/how-to-deploy-angular-application-to-heroku-1d56e09c5147) guide I am trying to deploy in Heroku my angular application but it fails during the build (`ng build --prod`) with the below error:

> 95% emitting index-html-webpack-pluginEROFS: read-only file system,
> mkdir '/dist' Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/dist'

As I see from related topics the issue seems to be in the npm version I am using but not quite sure if this is a bug or not. My current engines same as in local is:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "12.20.0",
    "npm": "6.14.0"
  }
```

Some important notes are that
`ng build --prod` runs successfully in my local and also
`node server.ts` renders the page as expected.

If anyone knows:

1. What else I can try to resolve the issue or
2. If has already deployed with success what npm & node version was used
   it would be very helpful.

Thanks in regards!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, I realized by testing again all the workflow that due to miss-configuration in angular.json, even though the `ng build` command was running with success, no dist file was generated.

So by fixing it everything worked like a charm.